# Github incorrectly detects Languages of my project as "Roff"

Tags: github

In one of my [repositories](https://github.com/FermiParadox/Tor_deanonymization) nearly all of my code is Python and some HTML.

However, Github thinks otherwise:

[image: github_languages_screenshot]

What causes that?

Comment: Would you mind marking my answer as the question's answer? Looking through my past work, I noticed this one was solved but never marked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You were creating files through a script, with an unintended extension. That is, your script was inserting a dot in the file name.

Simply rename your file `my_file_0.5ms` to `my_file_05ms.txt` and it will display the correct languages:

[image]

---

What you could do to fix similar problems in the future is use a script to detect extensions and the total lines of code for each extension.

Comment: GitHub uses Linguist to detect, categorize and count lines of code across many different languages. It can be configured in order to modify how it perceives (or *what* it perceives) the various files in a repository.

Comment: @Xevion That's a useful comment. Could you post it as an answer? In my case I accidentally created files with a name that contained a dot. Meaning they were considered extensions (as expected).

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

GitHub Linguist is the culprit in this situation, but luckily, it can be easily resolved in a number of ways.

Create a `.gitattributes` file and list patterns that match the files you want to ignore, and then append either `linguist-vendored` or `linguist-documentation`.

```bash
specific-file.5ms
*.5ms
specific-folder/*
```

This will remove the files from your GitHub repositories statistics on the next run of Linguist (it may take some time).

#### Notes

If you'd like to attribute these files to a specific language, you can do that using `linguist-language={name}`. Full documentation on overriding Linguist can be found [here](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/d7799da826e01acdb8f84694d33116dccaabe9c2/docs/overrides.md).

You can also run Linguist on your own computer, but note that any changes to `.gitattributes` will not take effect until you commit to your repository. Linguist will not see changes that exist only in the index.